# How to use ExternalEvaluate in ResourceFunction?

Tags: python, external-language-cell, external-calls

Are there any working examples or best practices for writing `ResourceFunction` that package or depend on external language code (and package dependencies) through `ExternalEvaluate`?

**Details:**

- I can’t think of any good way to do this wel across platforms
- primarily use cases are for Python and JavaScript.
- specifically, my python functions depend on both conda and pip libraries

  - Any ideas and/or working examples would be appreciated

Comment: Without a proper packaging system this isn't likely to work. `ResourceFunction` is basically a "weak" form of packaging that only works for Mathematica functions and only for some tiny subset of them anyway. You'd want a proper paclet to use other language capabilities. This is what happens with `JLink` and `LibraryLink` and all of these other, better developed hooks; they distribute their dependencies via paclets.